# Is condition considered a special word in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named condition, and whenever I try to query the table or insert data into it I am getting an error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PrisonDB`.`Condition` (
`condition_id` INT NOT NULL,
`condition_description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`condition_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And if I try to query it I get:

```
mysql> select * from condition;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition'
at line 1
```

Everything looks right to me, the only thing I can think of is condition is a special keyword or something in mySQL.

Comment: You can easily look up the full list... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because [Google exists](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mysql+reserved+words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `condition` is a reserved word [as of MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-new-5.0). Your original `Create Table` works because you can use ` to quote reserved words for use in table/field names.

Works:

```
SELECT * FROM `condition`;
DROP TABLE `condition`;
# etc.
```

Doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is check this link please

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

you should either use ` or change name of the table

Answer (score 0):

CONDITION is a reserved word in MySQL.