# Spring: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

First I want to sorry because my English is not good.
I'm studying Spring Framework and I'm making a simple Application using Spring Boot,Spring Data,Spring MVC.

Now I have an error but I don't know why.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'describe='Education', name_room='Boston', id_status='2' where id_room='1'' at line 1

This is my code:

```
Room Model

    @Entity
    @Table(name ="room")
     public class Room implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID_room", nullable = false)
        private String id;


        @Column(name = "name_room", nullable = false)
        private String name;


        @Column(name = "Describe")
        private String describe;

        @Column(name = "ID_status")
        private String status;

        public Room() {
            super();
        }

        public Room(String id, String name, String describe, String status) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.describe = describe;
            this.status = status;

        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescribe() {
            return describe;
        }

        public void setDescribe(String describe) {
            this.describe = describe;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }


}

RoomController

    @GetMapping("/manager/{id}/edit")
    public String edit(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("room", romService.findOne(id));
        return "roomForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/manager/save")
    public String save(@Valid Room room, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "roomform";
        }
        romService.save(room);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("success", "Saved user successfully!");
        return "redirect:/manager";
    }
```

Code is working but I have an SQL error.. I don't know why.. Please help me

```
Hibernate: update room set describe=?, name_room=?, id_status=? where id_room=?
2018-06-08 09:41:12.881  WARN 9308 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2018-06-08 09:41:12.882 ERROR 9308 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'describe='Education', name_room='Boston', id_status='2' where id_room='1'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 9):

It is because 'describe' is a keyword in Mysql and should not be used. Give a different name to this field.

Or if you want to use keyword as a field name then describe only then put it like this. In between   `**describe**` (back-tick character)

Comment: same thing happen with me with the keyword "usage". Your answer helped out. ty

Comment: Glad it helped you...:)

Comment: Thank you, mine was *condition* . Reference answere at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571966/is-condition-considered-a-special-word-in-mysql#:~:text=Yes%2C%20condition%20is%20a%20reserved,TABLE%20%60condition%60%3B%20%23%20etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try update name = "Describe" to "`Describe`"

```
        @Column(name = "`Describe`")
        private String describe;
```

Comment: You saved my day. I have got in similar error where i have used `key` as name.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using SQL keywords as column names, even using "desc" will throw the same error(I got that!). Use any other column name instead of "Describe".