# how can spring integration 5.5.x use mysql as message store

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-jdbc

I'm using Mysql as message store DB, just tried to upgrade to spring integration 5.5.5, but found the schema changed,
there requires a `CONDITION` column in INT_MESSAGE_GROUP table, although I can create the table by adding backtick around `CONDITION`, there is a  sql in JdbcMessageStore.java

```
    GET_GROUP_INFO("SELECT COMPLETE, LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE, CONDITION" +
            " from %PREFIX%MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?")
```

it cannot work?
any work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I see now. Looks like `condition` is a reserved word in MySQL: [Is condition considered a special word in mySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571966/is-condition-considered-a-special-word-in-mysql). Not sure how I have missed that, but this is considered as a bug and have to be really fixed from the framework perspective.

The workaround depend on the fact what you are doing with that `JdbcMessageStore`. If you use it from the queue channel, then it is better to look into a `JdbcChannelMessageStore` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store-channels.

If you really deal with an aggregator, then you have to extend `JdbcMessageStore` and override `getGroupMetadata()` and `setGroupCondition()` where a `CONDITION` is in use for SQL statements.

Or just look into some other DB vendor which doesn't reserve `CONDITION` word!

I'm going to fix it via `GROUP_CONDITION` word instead...

**UPDATE**

The fix for the framework code is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3687. The next Spring Integration `5.5.7` will be released like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/milestone/80. Just in time for the next Spring Boot versions!

Comment: Thank you, Artem, yes, we have some aggregation cases,